# Installing APC on CentOS 5.5 64bit error?

Tags: centos, pecl

```
# sudo pecl install apc
downloading APC-3.1.6.tgz ...
Starting to download APC-3.1.6.tgz (-1 bytes)
....done: 3,585 bytes
Could not get contents of package "/tmp/tmpspT8Og/APC-3.1.6.tgz". Invalid tgz file.
Download of "pecl/apc" succeeded, but it is not a valid package archive
Error: cannot download "pecl/APC"
[root@D18634 tmp]#
```

What does this error mean? How do I fix it, thank you.

Comment: it looks like it doesn't download the archive correctly. try again later.

Comment: Is `/tmp` (or `/`) full? Always the first thing to check!

Comment: It is a known bug that has a workaround, as posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23762141/pear-succeeded-but-it-is-not-a-valid-package/

Answer (score 1):

would not be surprised to find that 3k file is an html page.
perhaps a 404 or a 503?
Also, did you install the pre-requisites? The default CentOS 5.5 requires up-to-date php-pear, php-devel, and httpd-devel before pecl can run and compile apc.